# How can I synchronize Docker container registry with a GitHub action in the same repository?

Tags: docker, github-actions

I have a repository with a Dockerfile and a custom action described by action.yml which references that Dockerfile. At first, I referenced the Dockerfile locally as a path in action.yml using `image: 'Dockerfile'`. However because GitHub doesn't support caching for Docker image and rebuilds it on every run, it takes a long time to prepare and clutters the logs, and it also doesn't have the required entrypoint file. Thus I upload it to the GitHub container registry on push to master. The problem is now, that it always points to the master tag, which means the tests may be executed on an outdated version as it may not be deployed yet, and I also can't pin tags to the associated tag of the image or go back and get an older state. How can I synchronize the image on the GitHub container registry to the associated state in the repository?

### action.yml

```yaml
[...]
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: docker://ghcr.io/orgaization/repo:master
[...]
```

### .github/workflows/test

```yaml
 
on:
  workflow_dispatch:   
  push:
    branches: ['master']
  pull_request_target:
    branches: ['master']
  
jobs:
  test-correct:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: test
        uses: ./
        with:
[...]
```

### .github/workflows/publish

```yaml
on:    
  workflow_dispatch:   
  push:
    branches: ['master']
  pull_request_target:
    branches: ['master']
  
env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}
          
jobs:
  build-and-push-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: 
      contents: read
      packages: write
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
     [...]
      - name: Log in to the Container registry
     [...]
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

Comment: The phrasing of the question is a bit confusing. I believe what you really want to do is cache the previous build results and utilize that cache on the future builds, so they don't run again. I'd also restructure the logic, build your image first with a unique tag, test using that unique image, and then release/publish by retagging that image in the registry.

Comment: @BMitch: I actually have a very simple goal: a docker image should always be built exactly once on push and then exactly that image should be used by the action in that commit. The same ways as it would be when using `image: 'Dockerfile'` only with a prebuilt image.